# overloaded operator<< and operator+ causing error

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
class student
{
 private:
     int age;
 public:
     student();
     student(int a) {age = a;}
     ~student() {};
     friend student& operator+ (int left, student& s);
     friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& o, student& s);
}

...

student& operator + (int left, student& s)
{
    s.age += left;
    return s;
}

ostream& operator<< (ostream& o, student& s)
{
    o << s.age << endl;
}


int main (void)
{ 
    student a (10);
    cout << 14 + a ;
    return 0;
}
```

So I have two questions from the above code.

1. Why do you have to do `return s;` in the `operator+ (int left, student& s)` function? 
   why can't you just put the return type as `void` since you're already passing `student` object by reference?
2. It seems that I get an error whenever I put `endl` after `14 + a`, I catch an error and it doesn't print. I know this has something to do with `operator <<', but I don't know the exact reason for it, and how do you prevent this from happening?

Comment: `operator+` should return `student` and not randomly modify its argument.

Comment: *What* error do you get with `endl`?

Answer (score 6):

> Why do you have to do return s; in the operator+ (int left, student& s) function?

I must say your definition of `operator +` is strange, as it modifies the right side object - while `operator +` normally does not, and returns a new object by value.

Anyway, `operator +` normally does not return `void` so that it allows chaining, as in:

```
14 + (16 + a)
```

But again, `operator +` is not supposed to modify the right side object. You probably meant to write something like `operator +=`. Consider changing the definition of your `operator +`.

> It seems that I get an error whenever I put endl after 14 + a, I catch an error and it doesn't print. I know this has something to do with `operator <<', but I don't know the exact reason for it, and how do you prevent this from happening?

Your program has undefined behavior, because your overload of `operator <<` does not return anything. You should add a return statement:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& o, student const& s)
//                                       ^^^^^
{
    o << s.age << endl;
    return o;
//  ^^^^^^^^^ <== Without this, your program has undefined behavior.
//                Value-returning functions MUST return a value (with
//                the only exception of main())
}
```

Also, as done above, you should accept the `student` object by reference to `const`, since the `operator <<` is not going to alter its state (if you didn't do that, you could not use `operator <<` with a `const` object.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm trying to make an overloading operator+ when the non-object type is on the left, just for practice. So when you do  `a.operater+ b`(this code is not implemented in the code up there)  for example, the operation is acted on object a right? then in `14+a` should I say the operation is acted on object a as well?

Comment: Adding an `int` to change the age is clearly operator overloading abuse (in addition to your comments about operator `+` modifying one of its arguments.

Comment: +1 and also change parameter type in `operator<<` to `student const&`.

Comment: @MoreCode: I'm not sure I understand your question, but I believe James Kanze and hmjd kind of answered it ;)

Comment: @hmjd: Right, I overlooked that in the first place. Edited, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Concerning 1, you don't have to do anything.  The language
imposes no restrictions on what you do with an overloaded
operator.  Maintainability and readability, on the other hand,
do require that the overloaded operator behave in some way like
the corresponding built-in operator.  Thus:

- It makes no sense to overload addition for a type named
  `student`, since it makes no sense adding students.  (On the
  other hand, your class `student` really seems more like an
  abstraction of `StudentAge`.)
- Addition (operator `+`) does *not* modify either of its
  arguments.  With almost no exceptions.  In your case (supposing
  `StudentAge`, rather than just `Student`), I could see three
  operators: `StudentAge operator+( StudentAge const& lhs, int rhs
  )`, `StudentAge operator+( int lhs, StudentAge const& rhs )`,
  and above all, `StudentAge& StudentAge::operator+=( int rhs )`.
  The last *would* change `this`, and the first two should
  probably be implemented in terms of this third overload.
- All of the overloaded addition operators should return
  something, because this is what the built-in operator does.
  `operator+` returns a new object, and `operator+=` returns
  a reference to `this` (`return *this;`).  Again, always.

Anything else is abuse, and only serves to confuse the reader.

With regards to your second question: you've declared
`operator<<` to return something, so implement it to return
something.  Just falling off the end is undefined behavior (even
without anything else following).

Answer (score 0):

For 1), consider the following code :

```
student aStudent = anotherStudent + aDifferentStudent;
```

Here, we take two arguments and return a value. This is why you need to return an instance of the class. Your current implementation is not a standard way of doing the operator+ function, as it modifies the arguments. Consider the string operator+ used here:

```
std::string aString = "Hello" + " " + "World";
```

Operating from right-to-left, " " and "World" are literal strings, passed to the function, which returns " World", which is then passed along with "Hello" to the function again (as you have 2 calls to the operator+ method) to finally return "Hello World". Your implementation cannot do that, as A) the function parameters are not declared const, and B) if they were, and it did a const-cast to modify, you'd be attempting to modify a string literal - undefined behaviour.

String is a good example of how one expects the operator+ overload to work, in order to avoid breaking the principal of least surprise.

As for your << and endl issue, this is similar in principal. You need to return the o instance.